# Cannot get latitude and longitude from address in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude from the address but it does not work

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);    

try {
       List<Address> addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Salem, Tamil Nadu", 5);
       if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
           double lat = addressList.get(0).getLatitude();
           double lng = addressList.get(0).getLongitude();
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " This is for the :"+lat+"long:"+lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

it does not show even empty toast message . toast message also it not working. i think . after   `if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0)` line nothing executes

i removed this if condition also even it is not working.

then `addressList.size()` has value is 0. even i give correct address at `getFromLocationName`

i tried with is answer even it is not working and how to lat and lng from `p1` object. the toast message also it not working

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
 List<Address> address;
 GeoPoint p1 = null;

 try {
     address = coder.getFromLocationName("Salem, Tamil Nadu",5);
     if (address == null) {

     }
     Address location = address.get(0);
     location.getLatitude();
     location.getLongitude();

     p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                       (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " this line works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
 catch(Exception ex){

 }
```

This is code is also not working i cant see anything inside the textview(Source)

```
 double lat= 0.0, lng= 0.0;

 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);    
 try 
 {
     List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Salem, Tamil Nadu, India" , 1);
     if (addresses.size() > 0) 
     {            
         GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                 (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                 (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

         lat=p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
         lng=p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

         Log.d("Latitude is:", ""+lat);
     Log.d("Longitude is:", ""+lng);
     source.setText(""+lat);

     }
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

error:

```
02-05 09:42:01.897: E/dalvikvm(1336): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint', referenced from method in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.MainActivity$1.onClick
02-05 09:42:01.897: W/dalvikvm(1336): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4019 (Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;) in Lin/wptrafficanalyzer/locationplacesautocomplete/MainActivity$1;
```

so i added the

```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

but if i use this line then my emulator is not working is show error like this

```
[2015-02-05 15:10:17 - LocationPlacesAutocomplete] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2015-02-05 15:10:17 - LocationPlacesAutocomplete] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-02-05 15:10:17 - LocationPlacesAutocomplete] Launch canceled!
```

so i removed it . what should i do now .

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet worked for me.

```
public  void getLatLongFromGivenAddress(String address)
    {
          double lat= 0.0, lng= 0.0;

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);    
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address , 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {            
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                lat=p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
                lng=p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

                Log.d("Latitude", ""+lat);
            Log.d("Longitude", ""+lng);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get lat and lng from tat `p1` objetc

Comment: `The constructor Geocoder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined ` error at ` Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);` so i changed to `MainActivity.this` but your code is not working

Comment: latitude cannot be resolved or is not a field in this line `double x=p1.latitude;`

Comment: friends please help me ! if it works i will mark your answer please

Comment: Are you sure you have imported play services also updated your manifest file with the required permissions

Comment: You using Android Studio?

Comment: No I'm eclipse for mobile development

Comment: Have you setuo Google Play services properly??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70296/discussion-between-goonerdroid-and-thamaraiselvam).